# Can't press any of the mat radio buttons when using Material Design

Tags: cordova, angular-material, radio-button, angular6, material-design

I am currently having an issue with not being able to select any of the radio buttons within the group that I have. For a little more background I am using Material Design 6.4.7, Angular 6, and Cordova to build a hybrid app for android. For some reason when I run the application and try pressing one of the choices nothing happens. This is a relatively new issue as it used to work but now all of a sudden it seems to have just broken all together.

This is my html for the radio group:

```
<mat-radio-group class="radio-group" [(ngModel)]="selectedVehicle">
    <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" style="font-size: larger; display: inline-block;  margin-right: 3%;" name="barcodeType" *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicleList" [value]="vehicle">{{vehicle}}</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-group>

<br><br>

<mat-radio-group class="radio-group" [(ngModel)]="printCount">
    <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" style="font-size: larger; display: inline-block;  margin-right: 14.5%;" name="printCount" *ngFor="let copy of possiableCopies" [value]="copy">{{copy}}
</mat-radio-button>
```

I have all of the required variables/arrays in my component file and as I said before it used to work so I don't think anything is wrong with that which is why I've come here because I'm at a loss for what might be wrong. I apologize if this is a little vague and if there is anymore information anyone needs I can post it however I really don't even know where to start as I cant even find a single instance of this happening online with a similar setup to mine. Thanks.

****EDIT 1:**
Here is the TS file for the component. I removed a few functions and data string the were irrelevant to this that I don't really want to post online but it shouldn't matter. Honestly if I had to guess now I feel like there might be something going on with how I've been using ngZone. The way I call functions in it was a work around that I found but I don't really know much about it or if it has negative implications as I was in a crunch and had to get it working.

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { DialogService } from "./../dialog-service.service"
import { PrinterData } from '../printer-data';
import { StockTypeDialogComponent } from '../stock-type-dialog/stock-type-dialog.component';
import { BarcodePreviewDialogComponent } from '../barcode-preview-dialog/barcode-preview-dialog.component'
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

export interface StockDialogData {
  stockType: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-barcode-printing-view',
  templateUrl: './barcode-printing-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./barcode-printing-view.component.scss']
})
export class BarcodePrintingViewComponent implements OnInit {

  stockDialogRef: MatDialogRef<StockTypeDialogComponent>;
  previewDialogRef: MatDialogRef<BarcodePreviewDialogComponent>;

  _printer: PrinterData;

  barcode: string;
  bcCharacter: string = 'T';
  dataToPrint:string = '';
  stockType: number = 0;

  printCount: number = 1;
  selectedVehicle: string = "T";
  vehicleList: string[] = ['Trailer', 'Dolly', 'Van', 'Door'];
  /*radioData: object[] = [
    {"type":"Trailer", "bcLetter":"T", "checked":true, "count":1},
    {"type":"Dolly", "bcLetter":"D", "checked":false, "count":2},
    {"type":"Van", "bcLetter":"V", "checked":false, "count":3},
    {"type":"Door", "bcLetter":"Y", "checked":false, "count":4}
  ]*/
  possiableCopies: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  testPrint = "";

  printAlignString = []; 
  // 0: Black Thermal Stock (TESTED), 1: White Linered Stock (TESTED), 2: White Linerless Stock (SHOULD WORK BUT NOT TESTED)

  constructor(public stockDialog: MatDialog, public previewDialog: MatDialog, private router: Router, private service: DialogService, private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._printer = this.service.getPrinter();
    this.barcode = this.service.getBarcode();
    this.bcCharacter = this.barcode[0];
    //this.setStockType(1);
    console.log();
  }

  initialPrint() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      //this.setStockType(this.stockType);
      this.dataToPrint = this.labelFormatter(0);
      for(var i = 0; i < this.printCount; ++i) this.print();
      //if(this.stockType != 2) this.setStockType(2);
    });
  }

  openPreviewDialog() {

    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.previewDialogRef = this.previewDialog.open(BarcodePreviewDialogComponent, {
        disableClose: false,
        hasBackdrop: true
      });

      this.previewDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log('Barcode preview dialog closed - selected: ' + result);
        if(result) this.initialPrint();
      });
    });
  }

  openStockDialog() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.stockDialogRef = this.stockDialog.open(StockTypeDialogComponent, {
        disableClose: false,
        hasBackdrop: true
      });

      this.stockDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log('Stock selection dialog closed - selected: ' + result);
        this.stockType = result;
        //this.setStockType(this.stockType);                                                                      **FIX ME
      });
    });
  }

  setStockType(x: number) {
    this._printer.service.print(this.printAlignString[x], this._printer.printer)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Stock type set');
    })
    .catch((reason) =>{
        console.log(reason);
    })
  }

  private print(){
    this._printer.service.print(this.testPrint, this._printer.printer)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((reason) =>{
        console.log(reason);
    })
  }

  cancel() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/scanHome']);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a theme  applied to the radio buttons? I have a custom theme and it causes all kinds of issues to not remember to apply, for example, `@include mat.radio-theme($my-theme);` in my themes scss file.

Answer (score -1):

U have one option? If yes u must use checkbox item.

Comment: I have 4 radio buttons in the group and I don't have any of them checked by default at the moment. When I run the app and try pressing any of them nothing happens. The circle doesn't even get filled in or checked. It's like the radio buttons aren't responding to anything  do. Also there are no errors or anything in the logs as far as I can see.

Comment: Is that what you wanted @Orates